# Transforming makefile to cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, gsl, clion

I was running a program using makefile and it looked like this:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -c -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include

OBJS = main.o Integr.o Data.o Interpolate.o

all: main
main: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o main
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp
Integr.o: Integr.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) Integr.cpp
Data.o: Data.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) Data.cpp
Interpolate.o: Interpolate.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) Interpolate.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

and then I wanted to debug my code using Clion, but I have problems with building it. CMakeList looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Desktop)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-o -g -std=c++11 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm")
add_definitions(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
include_directories(-I/usr/local/include)
set(SOURCE_FILES
    Data.cpp
    Data.h
    Integr.cpp
    Integr.h
    Interpolate.cpp Interpolate.h main.cpp)

add_executable(Desktop ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

And there are few errors, concerning gsl, they look like this:

```
undefined reference to `gsl_rng_env_setup'
```

Comment: This is not the proper syntax for CMake. You would rather use `target_link_libraries(Desktop gsl gslcblas m)`. If you'd stick with your variables then you would needed also to set `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"undefinied reference" is a linker error.
you have forgotten to link the libraries that you used in the Makefile.

Using CMake you would need to add this line after add_executable:

`target_link_libraries(Desktop gsl gslcblas m)`

Note that in CMake you don't use "-l" when listing the libs.

Remove the line where your edit CXX_FLAGS.

Answer (score 2):

CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is only passed to compile .o from .cpp, but the libraries you want to link should be passed to the link phase (to compile the executable/lib from .o).
Use the target_link_libraries() function to do so.